# Do these grammars produce the same language?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I was solving a problem on CFG and saw this "simplification" in two of the rules. I believe these two grammars produce the same language, however I was not able to prove it. 
Grammar 1 :
S -> A|B
A -> B | aAb | epsilon
B -> A | bBa

Grammar 2 :
Z -> aZb | bZa | epsilon
Any help will be appreciated
EDIT : fixed terminal symbols so they are  correct now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** you can try to prove that the language produced by this grammar is the set of words of even length with as many `a` is the first half as `b` in the second part. You can prove that with an induction on the size of the words that are produced.